# Maintain uploaded Pictures with Express and Mongodb - Best practise?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm working on a little service (Express, Mongodb) where Users can upload Images to their accounts in various places. Before I dive in I'd like to make sure I have the right strategy to manage(store, edit, delete, load) these uploaded pictures.

My initial idea was to

1. Upload the pictures into a folder with the users-id
2. Save a directory-link as string in the users db-model
3. And then in the frontend paste the url-strings into img-src

What really bugs me about this approach, is that the images basically need to be maintained (change image-names, delete images, add images, ...) in two places, the db-model (urls-strings) and the upload-folder-structure (path, image-names). This probably could be made easier with a set of helper-functions.

But still, is there a more elegant way to manage images with Mongodb and Express? Any best practise here?

Comment: What do you mean, "maintained"? Once you store it, you don't need to touch it again.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Clarified what I meant by "maintenance" in the original post.

Answer (score 2):

It's more or less like you described. You need to store an image somewhere (local filesystem or S3, doesn't matter) and you need a record in your database to reference it. And then use it somehow (render as img src or whatever). So you *will* have to do these three things, no way around it. Of course, cleaner/better code will make your life easier.

I'd like to advise against one thing, though: renaming files in the storage. That is fragile/error-prone. What if renaming fails, because there is already a file with this name?

Instead, store all files with random names (sha-1 of content or random uuid or something else) and store the original filename in your database (along with the actual file path, of course). This way, should you need it, you'll be able to "rename" the file without touching the storage.

Comment: That is a valuable tip, will definitely do that! Thank you!

Comment: While trying to implement it it seems even more convoluted.
Now there is one more thing to keep in synch: the register that stores the actual filename (random string) and the assigned virtual name. Don‘t these lookups also cost lots of performance? I feel I'll get rid of the renaming feature for now so I can keep just one filename.

Comment: @Seltsam: well, it depends. If you don't need original filename, then obviously you don't need to keep it. But generally, it's not any more complicated that storing the file path. It's just another column/field in the same model. `image_url` and `image_original_filename`, for example. This way, there's no "keeping in sync". Since they are fields on the same object, they refer to the same file.

Answer (score 0):

@Sergio This is how I approached it now. How would you work in the functionality for the randomized filenames? Thanks

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ImageSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  _id:false
})

ImageSchema.virtual('url').get(function () {
  var parent = this.parent()
  var root = (parent.parent ? parent.parent() : parent)
  return root.category + "/" + root.path +"/"+ this.name
});

ImageSchema.set('toJSON', {
    virtuals: true
});

var CombinationSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  description: String,
  images: [ImageSchema],
  _id:false
})

var CasinoSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    category: {
        type: String,
        default: 'casino'
    },
    images: [ImageSchema],
    path: String,
    description: String,
    combinations: [CombinationSchema]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('casinos', CasinoSchema)
```

Comment: I don't know node.js/express, so no idea what its file upload api looks like. But that's where you need to insert the random name logic.